# Possibility to return to ScanPage

Tags: c#, xamarin, qr-code

In Xamarin app, I have a page after scan a QR Code. An `AlertPage` to show if the ticket is good or not (I don't want a `DisplayAlert`). On this page I want a button to return to the page before the scanner, and an other button to return to scanner.

If you want I have 3 pages:

- `ListPeoplePage` (with a button to go to scan who create new `ZXingScannerPage`);
- `ScannerPage` (when you scan you go to `AlertPage`);
- `AlertScanPage` (with backbutton to go to `Scanner` and an other to go to `ListPeoplePage`).

I'm not sure if it's possible and I have problems with my `NavigationStack` (I have never the good number of pages).

If you know a good method to add this `AlertScanPage` it would help me.

My question is to go from `AlertScanPage` to `ScannerPage`.

Comment: Is your question about how to pop back to the `ScannerPage` or`ListPeoplePage` in `AlertScanPage`?

Comment: You can use a `navigationController` to navigate your pages. After scanned in `ScannerPage`, you can go to `AlertPage` by using `Navigation.PushAsync`. If you wan to back from `AlertScanPage` to `ScannerPage`, you can use `Navigation.PopAsync`. You can refer [navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical)